# Convert one modulus value to other

Tags: math, language-agnostic, modulus

Given N = A%B, how to find the value of A%C , where B > C.
You are given value of N and C, but not of A.

Is there any way to find this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics. It would fit better on the [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 8):

Nope. Consider the following:

```
A = 19
B = 10
C = 7
==> Given 9, you should get 5.

A = 29
B = 10
C = 7
==> Given 9, you should get 1.
```

So given the same input, there may be multiple answers.

Answer (score 2):

The modulo operation is one-way: given *a mod b = n*, all I can say is that *a* comes from the set of all other integers which, modulo *b*, equal *n*.

Let's demonstrate that this is impossible in general, taking B=3, C=2.

- *n* = *a* mod 3 = 1
- => a is in the set of integers {3x + 1}
- so consider, x=1

  - 4 mod 3 = 1, so that works
  - 4 mod 2 = 0
- now consider x=2

  - 7 mod 3 = 1, so we can't distinguish 4 from 7 knowing only *n* and *b*
  - 7 mod 2 = 1

That is, given *b=3* and *n=1*, you'd have to get two *different* answers without knowing *a*.

However, you may consider it's a special case that *b* and *c* here are coprime, and in fact are both prime. You can certainly solve this easily for some cases, such as *b=4* and *c=2*.

BTW, further discussion on this is probably better suited to [mathoverflow](https://math.stackexchange.com/)